# JSF application giving 404 for a sub-context

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, httpcontext, context.xml

My JSF application works in my local tomcat for URL like http://localhost:8080/MyApp/admin, but not on the hosting server, the URL there is http://www.myapp.com/admin
Do I need to do something with 'context.xml'/ put BocBase & AppBase. I got these things googling, but could not understand what exactly I have to do. Can anyone help me with the exact thing thats has to be done to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

This is described in [Tomcat's Configuration Reference - The Context Container](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html)

> #### docBase
>
> The *Document Base* (also known as the *Context Root*) directory for this web application, or the pathname to the web application archive file (if this web application is being executed directly from the WAR file). You may specify an absolute pathname for this directory or WAR file, or a pathname that is relative to the `appBase` directory of the owning [Host](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html).
>
> The value of this field must not be set when the Context is configured using a `META-INF/context.xml` file as it will be inferred by the automatic deployment process.

Your URL indicates that you want to have it on a document base of *root*. So it should be set to `/`.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give me an example?

Comment: An example of what? Setting docbase to root speaks for itself: `docBase="/"`. Do it in the associated `<Context>` element in the `context.xml` file.